# sunbeam cluster bootstrap coomand for openstack giving message "WARNING: Minimum system requirements (4 core CPU, 16 GB RAM) not met."

Tags: 22.04, openstack

I am trying to install Openstack on a  VM  Ubuntu 22.04 on KVM as below (implementation for nested VM. I am following step by step on https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-openstack-on-your-workstation-and-launch-your-first-instance

```
$ free

               total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available Mem: 

            16373288     1013824    11315364        1272     4044100    15034988
Swap:        4194300           0     4194300
```

```
$ lscpu | grep "CPU\|vendor\|Virtualization"

CPU op-mode(s):                     32-bit, 64-bit

CPU(s):                             4

On-line CPU(s) list:                0-3

Model name:                         Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-8700K CPU @ 3.70GHz

CPU family:                         6

Virtualization:                     VT-x

Hypervisor vendor:                  KVM

Virtualization type:                full

NUMA node0 CPU(s):                  0-3
```

But when I run `sunbeam cluster bootstrap --accept-defaults` , it gets the following warning message:

```
WARNING: Minimum system requirements (4 core CPU, 16 GB RAM) not met.
```

Would like to know if it is a cosmetic error in the warning message logic or somthing else to investigate?